# how do i fix this error with fivem i get script error

Tags: server, lua, fivem

```
SCRIPT ERROR: @sessionmanager/server/host_lock.lua:25: attempt to compare number with nil  
[script:sessionmanage]> handler (@sessionmanager/server/host_lock.lua:25)
```

the script:

```
-- whitelist c2s events
RegisterServerEvent('hostingSession')
RegisterServerEvent('hostedSession')

-- event handler for pre-session 'acquire'
local currentHosting
local hostReleaseCallbacks = {}

-- TODO: add a timeout for the hosting lock to be held
-- TODO: add checks for 'fraudulent' conflict cases of hosting attempts (typically whenever the host can not be reached)
AddEventHandler('hostingSession', function()
-- if the lock is currently held, tell the client to await further instruction
if currentHosting then
TriggerClientEvent('sessionHostResult', source, 'wait')

        -- register a callback for when the lock is freed
        table.insert(hostReleaseCallbacks, function()
            TriggerClientEvent('sessionHostResult', source, 'free')
        end)
    
        return
    end
    
    -- if the current host was last contacted less than a second ago
    if GetHostId() >= 1 then
        if GetPlayerLastMsg(GetHostId()) < 1000 then
            TriggerClientEvent('sessionHostResult', source, 'conflict')
    
            return
        end
    end
    
    hostReleaseCallbacks = {}
    
    currentHosting = source
    
    TriggerClientEvent('sessionHostResult', source, 'go')
    
    -- set a timeout of 5 seconds
    SetTimeout(5000, function()
        if not currentHosting then
            return
        end
    
        currentHosting = nil
    
        for _, cb in ipairs(hostReleaseCallbacks) do
            cb()
        end
    end)

end)

AddEventHandler('hostedSession', function()
-- check if the client is the original locker
if currentHosting ~= source then
-- TODO: drop client as they're clearly lying
print(currentHosting, '~=', source)
return
end

    -- free the host lock (call callbacks and remove the lock value)
    for _, cb in ipairs(hostReleaseCallbacks) do
        cb()
    end
    
    currentHosting = nil

end)

EnableEnhancedHostSupport(true)
```

i tried searching on google but i didnt found anything

Answer (score 0):

correct the block:

```
if GetHostId() >= 1 then
    if GetPlayerLastMsg(GetHostId()) < 1000 then
        TriggerClientEvent('sessionHostResult', source, 'conflict')  
        return
    end
end
```

here you need to check for nil or not allow nil when comparing numbers:

```
local HostId = GetHostId() or 0
if HostId >= 1 then
    if GetPlayerLastMsg(HostId) < 1000 then
        TriggerClientEvent('sessionHostResult', source, 'conflict')
        return
    end
end
```